# How do I style a table within Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner coder and I am currently trying to make a comparison table using Javascript.  Once I have inserted the html into the string in Javascript it is not centered under the product image.  Some help will be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Below is my HTML, CSS and Javascript

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  var features = [];
features['product1'] = "<img src=\"images/product.png\" id=\"productImage\"alt=\"product image\"><li>R11 799</li><li>16GB</li><li>4.7 Inches</li><li>5.44 Inches x 2.64 Inches x 0.28 Inches</li><li>5.04 oz.</li><li>12 MP Rear / 5 MP Front</li><li>2015</li><li>Siri personal assistant</li><br></br>".replace(/"/g, "");
features['product2'] = "<img src=\"images/product2.png\" id=\"productImage\"alt=\"product image\"><table><tr><td class=\"rowTitle\">Price</td><td>R12 399</td></tr><tr><td class=\"rowTitle\">Memory</td><td>32/64/128 GB</td></tr><tr><td class=\"rowTitle\">Resolution</td><td>1440 x 2560 pixels</td></tr><tr><td class=\"rowTitle\">Dimensions</td><td>143.4 x 70.5 x 6.8 mm</td></tr><tr><td class=\"rowTitle\">Weight</td><td>138 g (4.87 oz)</td></tr><tr><td class=\"rowTitle\">Pixels</td><td>16 MP Rear / 5 MP Front</td></tr><tr><td class=\"rowTitle\">Model Year</td><td>2015</td></tr><tr><td class=\"rowTitle\">Special Features</td><td>Wireless charging</td></tr></table>".replace(/"/g, "");
features['product3'] = "<img src=\"images/product3.png\" alt=\"product image\"><li>R11 799</li><li>16GB</li><li>4.7 Inches</li><li>5.44 Inches x 2.64 Inches x 0.28 Inches</li><li>5.04 oz.</li><li>12 MP Rear / 5 MP Front</li><li>2015</li><li>Siri personal assistant</li><br></br>".replace(/"/g, "");
features['product4'] = "<img src=\"images/product4.png\" alt=\"product image\"><li>R11 799</li><li>16GB</li><li>4.7 Inches</li><li>5.44 Inches x 2.64 Inches x 0.28 Inches</li><li>5.04 oz.</li><li>12 MP Rear / 5 MP Front</li><li>2015</li><li>Siri personal assistant</li><br></br>".replace(/"/g, "");
features['product5'] = "<img src=\"images/product5.png\" alt=\"product image\"><li>R11 799</li><li>16GB</li><li>4.7 Inches</li><li>5.44 Inches x 2.64 Inches x 0.28 Inches</li><li>5.04 oz.</li><li>12 MP Rear / 5 MP Front</li><li>2015</li><li>Siri personal assistant</li><br></br>".replace(/"/g, "");
features['product6'] = "<img src=\"images/product6.png\" alt=\"product image\"><li>R11 799</li><li>16GB</li><li>4.7 Inches</li><li>5.44 Inches x 2.64 Inches x 0.28 Inches</li><li>5.04 oz.</li><li>12 MP Rear / 5 MP Front</li><li>2015</li><li>Siri personal assistant</li><br></br>".replace(/"/g, "");

function compareProducts(sel, suffix) {
  if (sel.value != "") {
    //header
    document.getElementById("header" + suffix).className = "selected";
    document.getElementById("header" + suffix).innerHTML = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

    //features
    document.getElementById("features" + suffix).className = "selected";
    document.getElementById("features" + suffix).innerHTML = features[sel.value];
  } else { //nothing selected, set to default
    //header
    document.getElementById("header" + suffix).className = "default";
    document.getElementById("header" + suffix).innerHTML = '';

    //features
    document.getElementById("features" + suffix).className = "default";
    document.getElementById("features" + suffix).innerHTML = '';
  }
} < /script>
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";



/* CSS Document */


* {
  font-family: aileron;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2A2A2A;
}


.logo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}
  

.default {
  font-style: bold;
  color: #262626;
}
.selected {
  font-style: normal;
  color: black;
}
#form {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#vs {
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
}
#dropDowns {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}
.select1 {
  margin-left: 20%;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
}
.select2 {
  margin-right: 20%;
  float: right;
  clear: left;
}
#table {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top-margin: 6em;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #0c3053;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
}
.top-info {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.features-list li {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 25px 40px;
  /*border-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .features-list li {
    font-size: 1.6em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Compare Products</title>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<link rel="icon" type="images/favicon.png" href="images/favicon.png">

<body>

  <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
  </div>


  <form id="form">

    <div id="dropDowns">
      <select class="select1" name="selProduct1" onchange="compareProducts(this, 1);">
        <option value="">Select Product</option>
        <option value="product1">Apple iPhone 6S</option>
        <option value="product2">Sumsung Galaxy S6</option>
        <option value="product3">HTC One M9</option>
        <option value="product4">Moto X Pure Edition</option>
        <option value="product5">Samsung Galaxy Note 5</option>
        <option value="product6">Huawei Ascend P8 Lite</option>
      </select>

      <div id="vs">
        <img src="images/vs.png" alt="VS." />
      </div>

      <select class="select2" name="selProduct2" onchange="compareProducts(this, 2);">
        <option value="">Select Product</option>
        <option value="product1">Apple iPhone 6S</option>
        <option value="product2">Sumsung Galaxy S6</option>
        <option value="product3">HTC One M9</option>
        <option value="product4">Moto X Pure Edition</option>
        <option value="product5">Samsung Galaxy Note 5</option>
        <option value="product6">Huawei Ascend P8 Lite</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <th id="header1" class="default"></th>
        <th id="header2" class="default"></th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="features1" class="default"></td>
        <td id="features2" class="default"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would not recommend constructing raw HTML via JavaScript. Use document.createElement() instead, if you really must do dynamic creation of HTML via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Some things worth noting

1. list items (li) should be contained within either ul or ol tags. If you want them unstyled, set list-style-type to none (of ul/ol)
2. you have 'features-list li' in your css, but no 'features'(which is what your array is called), and theres no sign of any features-list in your html
3. You have no style set for your img tag. That would help!

Fix the above and you'll be going places

Regards

Rachel

Comment: @NicB please accept my answer if this helps you... you can do so by hovering to the left hand side of the answer. An outline of a check mark appears on hover. When you click it, it turns green and the answer is considered 'accepted', plus you gain 2 points in reputation.. Thx

Answer (score -1):

here is a good [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp). There are some short and easy examples.

this code is an example from the link above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Colored Table Header</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

and it looks like

[image]

Comment: posting link-only answers is not good practice as links break. Post relevant code and reference the link you took it from or refrain

Comment: Thank you Rachel! I'll try what you have suggested and see if it works :)